# How to not notify fans when posting on my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-notifications

I have old stuff to post on my Facebook page and I would like my "fans" not to be notified about it.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Facebook page is a public profile, so anytime you post anything on page it will be visible to page 'fans'. If you want 'fans' did not get notify just unpublish your page.

Published Page is visible to the public. Unpublished Page is only visible to the people who manage the Page. Unpublishing your Page will hide it from the public, including the people who like your Page.

To unpublish your Page:

1. Click **Settings** at the top of your Page.
2. Click **Page Visibility**.
3. Click to check the box next to **Unpublish Page**.
4. Click **Save Changes**.

Your Page won't be visible to the public until you publish it again.

**Note:** You'll need to be an admin to unpublish your Page.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so there are a few ways... One, under the "liked" button on page is a drop down menu. Users clicking "notifications" under that can specify what they receive from the page.

The only other real way to do this, through Facebook, alone, is through paying for advertising, now... Facebook has unethically strangled organic reach so that  page admins have to literally pay just to reach the fans they used to be able to, for free..

Then 3rd party apps MUST do this, although I have not looked into it, yet. I intend to, tonight.